# ruby years hash generate

Tags: ruby, hash

I want to create hash with years to send it to form

How to create `{2011 => 2011, 2010 => 2010 ... 1990 => 1990}`

I tried like `@years = [2011..1990].each { |y| @year.push(y => y) }`

How to write this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your answer forwards: `Hash[(1990..2011).map{|y| [y,y]}]`

and backwards: `Hash[(1990..2011).map{|y| [y,y]}.reverse]`

Answer (score 1):

@Carl Zulauf answer is correct. I was thinking about using [zip](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000260):

```
1.9.2 (main):0 > range=1990..2000
=> 1990..2000
1.9.2 (main):0 > Hash[range.zip(range)]
=> {1990=>1990,
 1991=>1991,
 1992=>1992,
 1993=>1993,
 1994=>1994,
 1995=>1995,
 1996=>1996,
 1997=>1997,
 1998=>1998,
 1999=>1999,
 2000=>2000}
```